# Unknown flag in .MAP file format

Tags: visual-studio, parsing, dictionary, formatting, format

In the function mentioned below

```
0001:000000ef       ??0test_vtable_printf@@QAE@XZ 100010ef f i dllmain.obj
```

What do the flags `f` and `i` stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hopperx/archive/2006/09/14/754772.aspx), the "f" means "function".  There is no part 2 btw.

I can reverse-engineer "i" to "inline", a function in the COMDAT section.  Compare these two declarations:

```
class test_vtable_printf {
public:
    test_vtable_printf() {}    // Decorated with "f" and "i" in the map file
};
```

vs:

```
class test_vtable_printf {
public:
    test_vtable_printf();
};
test_vtable_printf::test_vtable_printf() {}  // Decorated with just "f"
```

Important to know, it tells you that setting a breakpoint at the address isn't likely to do what you hope it does.